# How to record only last X minutes in Android?

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, video-recording

I'm finding a way to record the screen only in last X minutes and have stuck for many days. I tried to use MediaRecorder but It seems not effective, It can only set the max duration for capturing. My code is below:

```
private void initRecorder() {
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment
                        .DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/video.mp4");
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(1000);
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an approach? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show your codes? Please elaborate "not effective".

Comment: Hi @Raptor, as I mentioned above, MediaRecorder only has `setMaxDuration(long maxDurationMs) ` method to define the video length, and that's not even what I'm looking for

Comment: Hi @Raptor, I've updated my code :)

Comment: I don't get it. If you can set the duration, you can record the screen for "last X minutes". Isn't it?

Comment: You mean record the screen until user click stop then cut the recored video for last X minutes? What happen if user record more than 3 hours and we don't have enough memory though we only need last 3 minutes?

Comment: There is no easy way to do that. What you could do is to record video piece by piece, and remove older pieces after they become irrelevant. And when the user stops recording, you can just take last X pieces.

Comment: @QuanHaAnh Vladyslav's solution is correct. You can capture screen piece by piece, and delete older videos, just like server logs (google "log rotation").

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko thanks for the solution, can you give me any keyword please? :)

Comment: well, just do what you do now, but set record time to let's say a minute, and after it finished - just start new one. Don't forget to use different file names. Also count how many videos you have recorded, store their file names in the list for example. So if you want last 10 ,minutes only, check the list size, and delete first item (and a file) from it before starting next record. To concatenate videos, you could use FFmpeg for example